# Use awk to modify a record in text file

Tags: bash, awk

I am attempting to use a bash script to modify specific records in a text based financial ledger.

Transactions are formatted like below. With a blank line between each.

```
2017-09-12 * Kroger Grocery
    ; UUID: a5d421aebeee0d976f8cfeabce3f8247
    ; Imported: 2017-09-12
    Assets:Banks:Checking                                          $ -100.00
    Expenses:General                                                $ 100.00

2017-09-12 * Another Payee
    ; UUID: 642c60861cdf8bc2ad96a9106112123e
    ; Imported: 2017-09-12
    Assets:Banks:Checking                                           $ -75.00
    Expenses:General                                                 $ 75.00
```

I have a bash script so far (using awk) that locates transactions in a set of files based on some input text and opens a temporary file in vim which contains all of the matching transactions.

After making changes and exiting any modified transactions are identified (again with awk) and returned as an array of transactions.

### Question:

I now need to locate the original of each modified transaction in the source file (probably by uuid string) and replace it with the modified transaction. I'm not sure the best way to do this. Can awk handle this easily? Or should I be looking for another solution?

### Output Clarification

Using the sample transactions I gave as a small source file, if the modified transaction array contains this transaction:

```
2017-09-12 * Another Payee
    ; UUID: 642c60861cdf8bc2ad96a9106112123e
    ; Imported: 2017-09-12
    Assets:Banks:Checking                                           $ -75.00
    Expenses:Some:Other:Account                                      $ 75.00
```

The source file should should now be:

```
2017-09-12 * Kroger Grocery
    ; UUID: a5d421aebeee0d976f8cfeabce3f8247
    ; Imported: 2017-09-12
    Assets:Banks:Checking                                          $ -100.00
    Expenses:General                                                $ 100.00

2017-09-12 * Another Payee
    ; UUID: 642c60861cdf8bc2ad96a9106112123e
    ; Imported: 2017-09-12
    Assets:Banks:Checking                                           $ -75.00
    Expenses:Some:Other:Account                                      $ 75.00
```

Comment: Please add expected output sample too in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' 'NR==FNR   {txn[$2]=$0; next} 
                                   $2 in txn {$0=txn[$2]}1' txn ledger

2017-09-12 * Kroger Grocery
    ; UUID: a5d421aebeee0d976f8cfeabce3f8247
    ; Imported: 2017-09-12
    Assets:Banks:Checking                                          $ -100.00
    Expenses:General                                                $ 100.00

2017-09-12 * Another Payee
    ; UUID: 642c60861cdf8bc2ad96a9106112123e
    ; Imported: 2017-09-12
    ; Update: 2017-09-12
    Assets:Banks:Checking                                           $ -95.00
    Expenses:General                                                 $ 95.00
```

with same ledger file and a modified txn file (inserted update row and modified amounts).

This assumes that your record always includes the UUID in the same location and format given (the row is used as the key); any new transactions won't be added (only updates).  Also there will be an extra new line at end of the file.

Comment: This is the perfect answer.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I really need to start learning awk. It's so useful.